# Ending a subroutine after a message box

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to figure out how to end my macro if you were to press no. However, before the macro has ended, I want to to run code. If the user were to press "yes", the code should proceed as normal. Here is my code:

```
Sub main()

    Call GriffinC_ISM_Table ' This Macro will create the pivot tables

    If MsgBox("Have you run this macro before", vbYesNo) = vbNo Then Call Spark_Table End Sub

    Call Extraps

End Sub
```

As you can see from this code, if the user presses no, I want to run the code "Spark_Table" and then end the sub. However, if the user presses "yes", I want to run the code "Extraps". Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

G

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Break it into lines like this (I'm shocked that even compiles...) (and it's `Exit Sub` if you want to terminate prematurely.) (and you don't really need to use `Call`) (and I added a "question" icon to your `MsgBox`)

```
Sub main()

  GriffinC_ISM_Table ' This Macro will create the pivot tables

  If MsgBox("Have you run this macro before?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion) = vbNo Then 
    Spark_Table
    ' put some code here to automatically send an email to the person who can help
    Exit Sub
  End IF

  Extraps

End Sub
```

...and make sure to test what happens if the user clicks on the `Close X` as it may return something other than `vbYes` or `vbNo`

Comment: Thanks so much. Worked like a charm

Answer (score 3):

try,

```
dim m as long

m = MsgBox("Have you run this macro before", vbYesNo)
if m = vbNo Then
    Call Spark_Table
    Exit Sub
elseif m = vbyes then
    Call Extraps
else
    '????? cancelled out of msgbox
end if
```